# Why does memory leak after large file download in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, performance, memory, memory-leaks

I have some Ruby that is downloading a large XML file (~ 380MB).

I'm using `on_body` to download it in chunks:

```
to = File.open('/path', 'wb')

http = HTTPI::Request.new(options)
http.url   = uri
http.on_body { |chunk| to.write(chunk) }

HTTPI.get(http, :net_http)

to.close
```

`on_body`, according to its documentation (https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/httpi/HTTPI/Request#on_body-instance_method) will read the response in chunks, to prevent filling up memory.

This seems to work, in practice my memory usage jumps up about ~178 MB after downloading the file, so some garbage collection appears to happen while the file is being streamed, or else I would expect it to jump by the full file size.

However, afterwords, that 178MB just hangs around forever.

I've narrowed it down to being due to the file download. If I read the same XML file from disk, memory has only increased by about 4MB after I'm finished processing the file.

Comment: because you didn't close the file ??? try adding `to.close`

Comment: @engineersmnky I should have included that in the code sample - I do close it. (I've added it to the sample now)

Comment: For what it's worth, closing vs not closing doesn't have any impact on the memory usage.

Comment: Are you sure it hangs around forever maybe GC just hasn't gotten to it yet

Comment: I manually called GC.start and it didn't go away. Also as I process the data memory fluctuates up and down, so I think garbage collection is running.

Comment: Garbage collection frees memory for re-use by Ruby. Releasing memory to the OS is something else. https://www.sitepoint.com/ruby-uses-memory/ explains it better than I can.

Comment: @steenslag Thanks, that's really informative. So it sounds like downloading the file just uses a lot of memory and Ruby doesn't see any reason to give it back to the OS. I'm surprised that streaming a download, even of such a large file, would consume that much memory at once, but maybe each chunk comes in too fast for ruby to GC it, so they add up quickly and Ruby views the program as having used that much memory at once, so it wants to hold onto it.